# How to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^p (\ln x)^r = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

I want to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^p (\ln x)^r = 0$ if $p > 1$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$.

To show this, I wanted to use that $\lim_{x \to 0} x \ln x = 0$, and in fact if $p \geq r$ we can write that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^p (\ln x)^r = \lim_{x \to 0} x^{p-r}((x \ln x)^r)$$
and both terms of the product goes to 0 as $x \to 0$. Thus this part is okay.

I have trouble if $p < r$. I tried to do the same, but I have no result so far. Maybe by considering $(x \ln x)^p (\ln x)^{r-p}$ and then setting $y = \ln x$. Thus we obtain
$$ 
\begin{align*} 
\lim_{x \to 0} (x \ln x)^p (\ln x)^{r-p} 
&= \lim_{e^y \to 0} (e^y \cdot y)^p \cdot y^{r-p} \\
&= \lim_{y \to - \infty} (e^y \cdot y)^p \cdot y^{r-p} \\
&= \lim_{y \to - \infty} e^{py} y^r\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$
because the exponential goes "faster" to $0$ than a polynom diverges to infinity? Does it seem correct to you?

---

### Edit:

I will assume that we know that for $r \in \mathbb{N}$, 
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^r}{e^y} = 0.$$
**Step 1:** I will prove that for $p > 1$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$ (for my exercise), 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^r x}{x^p} = 0.$$
*Proof:* Let $y = \ln x$. Then $x = e^y$ and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^r x}{x^p} 
&= \lim_{e^y \to \infty} \frac{y^r}{e^{py}} & e^{px} \geq e^x \text{ as } p> 1 \text{ and } x \geq 0\\
&\leq \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y^r}{e^y}\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

**Step 2:** Now I can prove that under the same hypothesis for $p$ and $r$, 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x^p \ln^r x = 0.$$
*Proof:* Let $y = \frac{1}{x}$, thus $x = \frac{1}{y}$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} x^p \ln^r x &= \lim_{\frac1y \to 0} \frac{1}{y^p} \cdot \ln \left( \frac{1}{y} \right)^r\\
&= \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{- \ln^r y}{y^p}\\
&= 0,
\end{align*}
$$
which concludes.

I took $p > 1$ and $r \in \mathbb{N}$ because it is only what I needed for my exercise, but if you feel like editing and proving this for all $p. r > 0$, go ahead.

Comment: In fact $x^p|\ln x|^r\to 0$ for all positive $p,r.$

Comment: That's what I thought, but I did not manage to find a formal proof of this, thus I tried to do one myself, but I'm not sure it's 100% valid. 
In fact I simply needed $p > 1$ for an exercise.

Comment: For all positive $p$ and even negative $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us examine the following. Given \begin{equation} l > 0 \end{equation} we prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to0} ln(x)x^l = 0.
\end{equation}
Doing this comes straight from L'Hospitals' rule. We put the limit in the indeterminate form and get the following.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{ln(1/x)}{x^l}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{-1}{x} *\frac{1}{lx^{l-1}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-1}{lx^{l}} = 0
\end{equation}

Since \begin{equation} l>0 \end{equation}

We now have a very general statement. From here you can see that if you substitute l for p/r (p and r >0), you can put our new found limit to the power of r and still get 0 as your answer. More importantly, by distributivity, we get the wanted limit like so.

\begin{equation}
0=\lim_{x \to 0}(x^{\frac{p}{r}}ln(x))^r =\lim_{x→0}x^p(ln(x))^r
\end{equation}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this is very closely related to problems regarding big and little o notation. If you are interested, read about how ln(x) = o(x^a) for any positive a and you can see how when we put ln(x) to any power r>0, we still have it in o(x^a).

Comment: That's a nice proof. Do you have any reference for the notations o and O for ln(x)?

Comment: Yes. I study number theory and have recently been reading the wonderful works of A.J. Hildebrand. It may be a difficult read, but here are his notes on asymptotic estimates which include some proofs and facts about big and little o notations.

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to prove that $$\lim_{y \to - \infty} e^{py} y^r
= 0$$ using Lo'Hopital's Rule.

But you could just as easily start the problem by using Lo'Hopital's Rule, by first writing the expression as $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ (\ln x)^r}{x^{-p}}.$$ You would have to use Lo'Hopital's Rule $r$ times, but at the end you should get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ c}{x^{-p}}$$ where $c$ is a constant. Clearly, this last limit evaluates to $0$.